# How to setup Assimp as a separate project (git-submodule) using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, git-submodules, assimp

I have a problem with adding Assimp to my project (which consists of exe and library projects). Before Assimp I added GLFW, GLEW and GLM as git submodule to my project. What's more, I did it using CMake. Now I want to do same thing with Assimp but somehow I can't.

I successfully added it as submodule. Then, in my CMake file (of library project) I added this lines:

```
include_directories(assimp/include)
add_subdirectory(assimp)
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary PRIVATE assimp)
```

but compilation failed. Then I set some options:

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(INJECT_DEBUG_POSTFIX OFF)
```

but CLion told me that my exe file is corrupted. I created new test project (because why not) just for assimp, set same options (about assimp) and compilation succeeded. But program didn't want to run, next it "did" but didn't even enter main function (exited program with code 1). I'm using MinGW as a compiler, tried switching to Visual Studio compiler but with it compilation failed so I got back to MinGW.

I'm trying to do it that way (with CMake and Assimp as submodule) to make creating project cross-platform. Assimp install tutorial suggests building it with cmake (as a command in console or with "Cmake-GUI") and then create (by compiling/building) with - for example on Windows - Visual Studio and get the lib/dll file(s) but that's not what I want to do.

Any ideas what I did wrong? I'm rather new to CMake and makeing programs cross-platfrom so it may be a simple thing. For any answers - thank you in advance!

Comment: Problem description "... but compilation failed" is not the one for which we could help you. Instead, show **exact error message** you got. The same is about "... but CLion told me that my exe file is corrupted".

Comment: Yeah, that's true, sorry for that but now I'm dealing with program exiting with code 1 (and not even entering the main) so I thought details about previous problems weren't so important. I tried to get back to those settings (like without those set(...) in cmake file) but somehow compilation is successful also. I have no idea what's going on :(